# Select query for picking consecutive rows multiple times in a table

Tags: java, sqlite, select, android-sqlite, android-room

I have multiple tables with more than 100K records in each table in Android Room database and using MVVM pattern.

Each table have two columns, an id (Primary Key) and a String column.

Requirements : Select consecutive rows at multiple intervals where the interval length is known already.

Explanation: Lets assume, due to some background calculations, I have an interval of 200 where interval starts from 300 and ends at 500. I need to pick these 200 (500-300=200) rows after every 2K records through out the table. So in this case, query should select the 200 rows in the pattern written below

Row starting from 300 to 500 for first 2K records,

Row starting from 2300 to 2500 in second 2K records,

Row starting from 4300 to 4500 in third 2K records

and likewise till the end of table.

Currently i am arranging the query like this as i know the interval so

s1 and e1 is 300 and 500,

s2 and e2 is 2300 and 2500,

s3 and e3 is 4300 and 4500 and so on

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM CATEGORY_TABLE WHERE (id BETWEEN :s1 AND :e1 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s2 AND :e2 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s3 AND :e3 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s4 AND :e4 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s5 AND :e5 ) " +
            "OR (id BETWEEN :s6 AND :e6 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s7 AND :e7 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s8 AND :e8 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s9 AND :e9 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s10 AND :e10 ) OR" +
            " (id BETWEEN :s11 AND :e11 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s12 AND :e12 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s13 AND :e13 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s14 AND :e14 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s15 AND :e15 ) OR " +
            "(id BETWEEN :s16 AND :e16 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s17 AND :e17 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s18 AND :e18 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s19 AND :e19 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s20 AND :e20 ) OR " +
            "(id BETWEEN :s21 AND :e21 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s22 AND :e22 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s23 AND :e23 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s24 AND :e24 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s25 AND :e25 ) OR " +
            "(id BETWEEN :s26 AND :e26 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s27 AND :e27 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s28 AND :e28 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s29 AND :e29 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s30 AND :e30 ) OR " +
            "(id BETWEEN :s31 AND :e31 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s32 AND :e32 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s33 AND :e33 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s34 AND :e34 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s35 AND :e35 ) OR " +
            "(id BETWEEN :s36 AND :e36 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s37 AND :e37 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s38 AND :e38 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s39 AND :e39 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s40 AND :e40 )"+ 
"(id BETWEEN :s41 AND :e41 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s42 AND :e42 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s43 AND :e43 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s44 AND :e44 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s45 AND :e45 ) OR " +
 "(id BETWEEN :s46 AND :e46 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s47 AND :e47 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s48 AND :e48 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s49 AND :e49 ) OR (id BETWEEN :s50 AND :e50 )");
    List<Category> getCategorySpecificRows(int s1, int e1, int s2, int e2, int s3, int e3, int s4, int e4, int s5, int e5,
                                                         int s6, int e6, int s7, int e7, int s8, int e8, int s9, int e9, int s10, int e10,
                                                         int s11, int e11, int s12, int e12, int s13, int e13, int s14, int e14, int s15, int e15,
                                                         int s16, int e16, int s17, int e17, int s18, int e18, int s19, int e19, int s20, int e20,
                                                         int s21, int e21, int s22, int e22, int s23, int e23, int s24, int e24, int s25, int e25,
                                                         int s26, int e26, int s27, int e27, int s28, int e28, int s29, int e29, int s30, int e30,
                                                         int s31, int e31, int s32, int e32, int s33, int e33, int s34, int e34, int s35, int e35,
                                                         int s36, int e36, int s37, int e37, int s38, int e38, int s39, int e39, int s40, int e40,
    int s41, int e41, int s42, int e42, int s43, int e43, int s43, int e44, int s45, int e45, int s46, int e46, int s47, int e47, int s48, int e48, int s49, int e49, int s50, int e50);
```

And used this BETWEEN 50 times to iterate over 100K record table. It works correctly but with poor performance. It took around 500ms - 1500ms to send this data back to repository. What should be the better way of writing this query in order to make this data fetching time efficient.

Comment: The answer to mass data processing is kind of requirement to process this data locally .. no need to go over the internet ... as this data will always remain static. Secondly, the data is not redundant/duplicate for any table due to its nature.

Additionally, table data cannot be reduced in terms of total records :( ... As the interval and range can grow or shrink as per the calculations performed before triggering the query.

Answer (score 0):

> Row starting from 300 to 500 for first 2K records, row starting from 2300 to 2500 in second 2K records, row starting from 4300 to 4500 in third 2K recordsand likewise till the end of table.

You can use artihemtics! Module comes handy here:

```
select *
from category
where id % 2000 between 300 and 500
```

This makes the query shorter to write, but efficiency might still be a problem. Picking 300 rows every 2000 rows is likely to require a full scan anyway.

Comment: I don't know why but when i run this suggested query using Room DB, it returns the empty list.  @Query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE (id % :interval) BETWEEN :s1 AND :e1") List<Category> getCategorySpecificRows(int s1, int e1, int interval);

But if i run the query as i wrote in the question, it fetches the data
And as you said about the efficiency, the suggested query took more time in returning even though its empty ...

Additionally, when i tested this suggested query online at https://sqliteonline.com/, it works perfectly as required in our case